# Embedding Python in C++ and calling methods from the C++ code with Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I try to embed a Python script into my C++ program. After reading some things about embedding and extending I understand how to open my own python script and how to pass some integers to it. But now I'm at a point a do not understand how to resolve my problem. I have to do both, calling Python functions from C++ and calling C++ functions from my embedded Python script. But I do not know where I have to start. I know I have to compile a .so file to expose my C++ functions to Python but this is nothing I can do, because I have to embed my Python file and control it by using C++ code (I have to extend a large software with a script language, to make some logic easy to edit).

So, is there any way to do both things? Calling Python functions from C++ and calling C++ functions from Python?

This is my C++ code

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;


// <----------I want to use this struct in my python file---------
struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};


// Exposing the function like its explained in the boost.python manual
// but this needs to be compiled to a .so to be read from the multiply.py
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
    ;
}
// <---------------------------------------------------------------


int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) // in the main function is only code for embedding the python file, its not relevant to this question
{
    setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
            for (i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
                pValue = PyInt_FromLong(atoi(argv[i + 3]));
                if (!pValue) {
                    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                    Py_DECREF(pModule);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                /* pValue reference stolen here: */
                PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
            }
            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyInt_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my Python file

```
import hello_ext #importing the C++ file works only if its compiled as a .so
planet = hello.World() #this class should be exposed to python
planet.set('foo')

def multiply(a,b):
    planet.greet()
    print "Will compute", a, "times", b
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        c = c + b
    return c
```

Comment: If its not clear, I look for something like the `lua_register(lua_State* L, string name, function func)` for python.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In short, Python extensions that are statically linked with embedded Python need to have their module initializer function explicitly added to the initialization table before the interpreter is initialized.

```cpp
PyImport_AppendInittab("hello", &inithello);
Py_Initialize();
```

---

Boost.Python uses the [`BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/module.html#BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE-spec) macro to define a Python module initializer.  The resulting function is not the module importer.  This difference is similar to that of creating a `example.py` module and calling `import example`.

When importing a module, Python will first check if the module is a built-in module.  If the module is not there, then Python will then search the [module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) trying to find a python file or library based on the module name.  If a library is found, then Python expects the library to provide a function that will initialize the module.  Once found, the import will create an empty module in the modules table, then initialize it.  For statically linked modules, such as `hello` in the original code, the module search path will not be helpful, as there is no library for it to find.

For embedding, the [module table and initialization function](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function) documentation states that for static modules, the module initializer function will not be automatically called unless there is an entry in the initialization table.  For Python 2 and Python 3, one can accomplish this by calling  [`PyImport_AppendInittab()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_AppendInittab) before [`Py_Initialize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize):

```cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
  // ...
}

PyImport_AppendInittab("hello", &inithello);
Py_Initialize();
// ...
boost::python::object hello = boost::python::import("hello");
```

Also note that the Python's C API for embedding changed naming conventions for module initialization functions between Python 2 and 3, so for `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)`, one may need to use `&inithello` for Python 2 and `&PyInit_hello` for Python 3.

---

Here is  a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff54ee8e667acc8e) having an embedded Python import a `demo` user module, that will then import a statically linked `hello` module.  It also invokes a function in the user module `demo.multiply`, that will then invoke a method exposed through the statically linked module.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>  // setenv, atoi
#include <iostream> // cerr, cout, endl
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct World
{
  void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
  std::string greet()       { return msg;      }
  std::string msg;
};

/// Staticly linking a Python extension for embedded Python.
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<World>("World")
    .def("greet", &World::greet)
    .def("set", &World::set)
    ;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 3)
  {
    std::cerr << "Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  char* module_name   = argv[1];
  char* function_name = argv[2];

  // Explicitly add initializers for staticly linked modules.
  PyImport_AppendInittab("hello", &inithello);

  // Initialize Python.
  setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
  Py_Initialize();

  namespace python = boost::python;
  try
  {
    // Convert remaining args into a Python list of integers.
    python::list args;
    for (int i=3; i < argc; ++i)
    {
      args.append(std::atoi(argv[i]));
    }

    // Import the user requested module.
    // >>> import module
    python::object module = python::import(module_name);

    // Invoke the user requested function with the provided arguments.
    // >>> result = module.fn(*args)
    python::object result = module.attr(function_name)(*python::tuple(args));

    // Print the result.
    std::cout << python::extract<int>(result)() << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 1;
  }

  // Do not call Py_Finalize() with Boost.Python.
}
```

Contents of `demo.py`:

```python
import hello
planet = hello.World()
planet.set('foo')

def multiply(a,b):
    print planet.greet()
    print "Will compute", a, "times", b
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        c = c + b
    return c
```

Usage:

```
$ ./a.out demo multiply 21 2
foo
Will compute 21 times 2
42
```

In the above code, I opted to use Boost.Python instead of the Python/C API, with the C++ comments annotated with the equivalent Python code.  I find it to be much more succinct and far less error prone.  If a Python error occurs, Boost.Python will throw an exception and all reference counting will be handled appropriately.

Also, when using Boost.Python, do not invoke [`Py_Finalize()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#Py_Finalize).  Per the [Embedding - Getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html) section:

> Note that at this time you must not call `Py_Finalize()` to stop the interpreter. This may be fixed in a future version of boost.python.